# Bootstrap Datepicker Locale with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, locale, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using a Bootstrap Datepicker [available here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and everything is working fine.  However, I want to localize the calendar given a user's preferred language.  I've set the following when I initialize the datepicker:

```
locale: 'fr'
```

However, I get a console error that reads:

> Uncaught TypeError: locale() locale fr is not loaded from moment locales!

I am including MomentJS in my project:

```
<script src="/vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This is my first implementation so I feel like I'm missing something simple but just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error messages says, you just have to include the desired locale to solve your issue. If you need only `fr` locale, you can add something like this:

```
<script src="/vendors/moment/locale/fr.js"></script>
```

after `moment` import.

**EDIT:**

If you need multiple locales you can import `locales.js` instead of `fr.js`. Moreover moments provides a single file, `moment-with-locales.min.js`, with moment library + all supported locales.

If you want to dynamically set locale for you picker, you can use [`locale`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#locale) function:

```
// Example with german locale
var localeString = 'de';
$('#your-picker-id').data("DateTimePicker").locale(localeString);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  So that resolved the error but now the datepicker is in French regardless of whether or not I specify the locale.  I'll keep trying!

Answer (score 13):

Replace

```
/moment/min/moment.min.js
```

by

```
/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js
```

and it will work